# Unity Tag and Collider problem while player is jumping

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collider

This is my player's jump code:

```
void Update()
{
    float oldmoveHorizontal = moveHorizontal;
    moveHorizontal = Joystick.Horizontal;
    moveVertical = Joystick.Vertical;    

    if (isJumping == false && moveVertical >= .7f)
    {
        moveVertical = Speed * 70;
        isJumping = true;
    }

    ball_move = new Vector2(moveHorizontal, moveVertical);         
    ball_rigid.AddForce(ball_move);

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
         {
             isJumping = false;
         }        
    }
}
```

When ball touches under of the collider it can jump again. How can i block this situation ?
[image: this is image]

if you cant download: https://ibb.co/yVgXmrM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
    {
        foreach (ContactPoint2D item in col.contacts)
        {
            Debug.Log("Normal:" + item.normal);
            if (item.normal.y > 0 && col.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
            {
                isJumping = false;
                Debug.Log("Top of Collider");
            }
        }
    }}
```

I found my solution with checking top side of collider.
With this code way, if player touchs **top side of collider**, it's going to activate jump again.

Comment: Good idea checking `ContactPoint2D.normal.y`!! This is better than my answer :) You should select it as the best answer when stackoverflow lets you

Comment: You could also try a different approach. Instead of checking whether the player hits something to determine if he is jumping you could have a point at the player model's feet from which you would do a [`Physics.CheckSphere()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.CheckSphere.html) against the ground Layer Mask to determine whether the player is standing on the ground.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to check the position of the collision points of the collision and see any of them is "low enough" from the center of your player to be a jumpable collision:

```
private Collider2D playerCollider; 
private float playerJumpableOffset = 0.001;

void Start() { playerCollider = GetComponent<Collider2D>(); }

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    float jumpableWorldHeight = transform.position.y - playerJumpableOffset;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < col.contactCount && isJumping; i++)  
    {
        Vector2 contactPoint = col.GetContact(i).point; 
        if (contactPoint.y <= jumpableWorldHeight) 
        {
            isJumping = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help ! <3